# Date Range Picker Issues with DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatables, daterangepicker

I'm having trouble getting Date Range Picker to correctly filter out rows in DataTables, which is done through ajax.

Currently there are the functions to create the date picker, and click events on cancel and apply, and when the function to create the date picker dateranger() is in the DataTable initComplete, it will not work at all except for custom ranges only. The input field does not update either and is stuck on the first preset date range. This made me think there is something up with the apply event, but when you select preset date ranges, it triggers this event still.

When dateranger() is outside of initComplete, the input fields update properly when you select a new date range, but the variables for the start and end dates are undefined and not passing through properly, so the table does not change.

I have also tried placing dateranger() in document.ready after everything else, and the date picker does not load then.

My coworker thinks this is a race condition issue, but I can't figure out how to get all pieces to work together.

Below is the function for the table which is called in document.ready:

```
let date_max = null
let date_min = null

function fill_table(show_date=false){

  let extra_params = []

  if (show_date){
    extra_params.push("DateStart=" + date_min)
    extra_params.push("DateEnd=" + date_max)
  }

  $("#some_table").DataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "/data" + "?" + extra_params.join("&"),
    "destroy": true,
    "sPaginationType": "numbers",
    "autoWidth": false,
    "bjQueryUI": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bProcessing": false,
    "paging": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "pageLength": 30,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "columns": [
         {"data": 'element_date'},
         {"data": 'elemebt_type'},
         {"data": 'element_status'},
         {"data": 'element_id'},
      ],
      "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
      "columnDefs": [
        {
          "visible": false,
          "targets": [3]
        },
      ],
    "initComplete": function() {

      //date range picker input appending
      $("#some_table_wrapper .ui .row .eight").append('<input class="square form-control filter_element d-inline ml-5" id="date-range" name="dates" aria-label="date" style="max-width:max-content; min-width:250px;">');

      //date range picker builder
      dateranger()

      //filter dates on apply
      $('#date-range').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
          date_min = picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
          date_max = picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
          date_max = date_max.replaceAll("/", "-")
          date_min = date_min.replaceAll("/", "-")
          console.log("before filling table")
          console.log(date_min)
          console.log(date_max)
          fill_table(show_date=true)
      });

      // clear dates on cancel
      $('#date-range').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $('#date-range').val('');
        fill_table(show_date=false)
      });
    } //end of initcomplete
  }) 
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Can you share wich libraries are you using ?.

Comment: Yes, DataTables at https://datatables.net/ and Date Range Picker at https://www.daterangepicker.com/